# Getting the distinct count of rows that are in one dataset which dont exist in the other dataset, COGNOS BI report building

Tags: reporting, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, cognos

I'm working with semi-additive data, so account balances. I'm trying to create a report where I select a time period, from this time period I'm interested in account status at the start and end of the time period. With these two 'datasets' I want to do the following:

- Get the distinct count of account IDs that exist in the first dataset, but not the last
- Get the distinct count of account IDs that exist in the last dataset, but not the first

Cognos has built in this except/intersect functionality, but I'm a little concerned about using it. Worried that it will get very messy quickly. What is the best practice when it comes to creating what I'm describing here?

Comment: You could create singletons with their own query to get first/last data sets.  
Have you tried something like... count(distinct [account id] for [company],[period])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant solutions using window functions, but I like to use many, simple pieces so that the next person has some hope of supporting what I have done.

I think you'll need 4 queries:

Query1
Data item: AccountId
Filters: [date] = ?startdate? (+ as needed)

Query2
Data item: AccountId
Filters: [date] = ?enddate? (+ as needed)

Query3 = Query1 EXCEPT Query2  (lost)
Data item:  count(AccountId)

Query4 = Query2 EXCEPT Query1  (gained)
Data item:  count(AccountId)